# MySQl Bulk Rename, Alter , Update

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQl database with more than 200 tables. I want to do following on ALL tables in this database.

1. Update all table name by adding a constant to the name
2. Add column (Alter table) to each table
3. Update each table to set newly added column

Can someone please suggest an efficient way of doing this

Thanks
bhim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a couple of SQL statements that will generate the rename / add column SQL statements.

Then you can run the SQL Statements.

You haven't provided table names, or schemas, etc. so I can give guidance but not exact results.

So assuming your "adding a constant to the name" is prefixing "const_" to it, you could do something like:

```
SELECT 'RENAME TABLE ''' || table_name || ''' TO ''const_' || table_name || ''' FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_catalog = 'YourCatalog' and table_schema = 'YourSchema';
```

This would give you the rename table command as the output, which you could pick up and put in a text editor to tidy up.

You'll need to execute a few queries against INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables to figure out the right filter to get the right criteria for the tables list.

And you can do similar for the Add column statement.

Some useful references:

Information schema: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html

Rename a table: https://blog.marceloaltmann.com/en-how-to-rename-table-in-mysql-pt-como-renomear-tabelas-no-mysql/

Add a column: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-add-column/

Comment: Thanks You this helped.